# How to write a module with Puppet for windows .lnk

Tags: windows, scripting, module, shortcut, puppet

I am using puppet to manage windows hosts and would like to know how I can edit the target field in a .lnk shortcut file to point to a new target, or to actually start with another manager binded.

I know where the shortcut files are I am just not sure how I can edit the target fields in the .lnk shortcuts properties using a module. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following document touches on managing .lnk shortcuts in windows:

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/2.5/quick_writing.html